# Jquery set value to input field based on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input field like:

```
<input data-checkout="card-number" type="tel" placeholder="card number" autocomplete="off" class="input-control" value="">
```

How I can set a value of this field with jquery? How to get `data-checkout="card-number"` and set value ?

Comment: Did you try $('[data-checkout="card-number"]').val("Your val"); ?

Comment: Thanks, this works good

Comment: Awesome, good luck.

Comment: Posted it as an answer if you want to mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

in jquery you can use any attribute as a selector using this format:

```
$('[your-attr="attr value"]')
```

Answering your question this should work:

```
$('[data-checkout="card-number"]').val("Your val");
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you wish to access it by. To access the element, you can use, for example:

```
$('.input-control')  // Finds all elements with this class
```

or

```
$('.input-control[data-checkout=card-number]')  // Finds all elements with this class and this data-checkout value
```

or some other selector, depending on your application. Then, to set the value you can do:

```
$(/* your selector */).val('some value'); // Sets the value to 'some value'
```

and to get the value fo data-checkout:

```
$(/* your selector */).data('checkout');  // Returns 'card-number'
```

It is somewhat unclear what exactly you are looking for, but hopefully some of this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you could use the val function:

```
$(".input-control").val("Some value")
```

Using javascript:

```
document.querySelector(".input-control").value="Some value"
```

You could get the attribute by:

```
$(".input-control").attr("card-number")
```

Then you can do

```
$(".input-control").val($(".input-control").attr("card-number"))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `.attr('card-number')` returns the value of `card-number="value"`. Use `.data('checkout')` do get the value of `data-checkout="value"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic Javascript to set the value.

```
for(i=0; card=document.querySelectorAll("input[data-checkout=card-number]")[i]; i++){
    card.value="sample value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[data-checkout="card-number"]').val('here') // replace word (here) with the value you want
```